# C: how to use strtok to get whats inside parenthesis?

Tags: c, string, parsing, strtok

I have a string "13657($t1)" which I get from a file and is stored in offset and I want to get the number before the "(" and then get $t1. this is what I have:

```
char *token = strtok(&offset, "("); // this works and i get 13657.
```

Now I need to get $t1 and I tried to do

```
char *token2 = strtok(&offset, "()"); //but it does not work. I should get $t1
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) for `strtok`.  You'll see that subsequent calls to return more tokens on the same string require `NULL` to be passed.  For any further help with this issue, please show a minimal compilable program demonstrating the issue, so we can see important information such as the _type_ of `offset`, how your reading and storing the string, etc.

Comment: If you don't like the behavior of the function `strtok` described in the previous comment, you may want to take a look at the function [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn) instead.

Comment: You may also want to look at the function [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) if you want to look for a single character. For example, you could first call `strchr` looking for the `'('` and then call `strchr` again looking for the `')'`.